# mvc 5 AD authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I just created a brand new MVC 5. Now I need to add AD Authentication. 
Basically I [followed this tutorial](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/).

My app compiles fine. No errors of any kind. But it doesn't authenticate either. When I tried logging in it redirects me to the login page. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have an existing MVC 4 application which I can authenticate using AD without issues. That tells me (in my own thinking) that my web.config file is ok.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
      </authentication>
      <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear />
              <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://primary.mydomain.local:389/DC=MyDomain,DC=Local" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why cannot you use the simplest Windows authentication, http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs It is far more easier to configure. The approach you use, is only useful when forms based authentication is required, and the IIS server is out of the target domain (or does not trust the target domain).

Comment: I wish it was for me to decide. Our organization requires forms based authentication.